# Why do function expressions have to be used to define methods inside a constructor function?

Tags: javascript

When messing around with constructor functions, I noticed that privileged methods written as function expressions, prepended with `this` work fine, whereas function declarations return a Type Error, where `function declaration is not a function`.

I understand that we can expose functions from an object instance by internally using `this` ie: `this.functionName`

```
var Foo = function(){
    var _color= "blue";
    this.getColor = function(){
            return _color;
    }
    function setColor(newColor){
       this._color = newColor;
        }
}
var bar = new Foo();
console.log(bar.setColor('red'));
```

What is going on behind the scenes regarding the function declaration `function setColor` leading to the log output being `Uncaught TypeError: bar.setColor is not a function` ? Does hoisting/the fact that the scope its declared in is a function expression have something to do with this?

Comment: It's a closure. - Javascript has lexical scoping, the constructors scope has no relation to its instance. You need to access the instance via `this`. You can assign it tho. `this.setColor = set Color`

Comment: I would also add that, plainly, `bar.setColor` is not a function because you've defined no property on `bar` called `setColor` (be it through its prototype, whatever). A function instantiated inside of another function isn't suddenly a method of its parent, like you might have syntactically in other languages.

Comment: there's nothing *privileged* about the `this.getColor` for example compared to `function setColor` ... `this.getColor` defines a function on the current instance (this), whereas `function setColor` just defines a locally scoped function - it's how javascript works

Comment: By the way, if you did "fix" setColor to be `this.setColor`, with your current code, `this.getColor` will *always* return `blue`, regardless if you called setColor or not ... because `this._color` is *not* the same variable as `var _color`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a closure. - Javascript has lexical scoping, the constructors scope has no relation to its instance. You need to access the instance via `this`.  You can store the function reference by assigning it in the constructor. `this.setColor = setColor`

Answer (score 3):

You cant try this:

```
var Foo = function(){
    var _color= "blue";
    this.getColor = function(){
            return _color;
    }
    this.setColor = function(newColor){
       this._color = newColor; 
       return this._color;
    }
}
var bar = new Foo();
console.log(bar.setColor('red'));
```

What happens is the function declaraction "**function setColor(newColor)**" is just an expression, enclosed within the scope of its parent function "**function()**". That means if you don't set/assign the "**setColor**" function to any property from the parent object (**Foo**) then it is not available from an outside (upper) scope. Also you had to return the value of "**this._color**" otherwise console.log will print "undefined".

Comment: yes the absence of the return was a type. I was returning the instance  with `this._color`